# Return specific character group in list of long strings

Tags: python

None of the answers I've seen here satisfy my condition. I need to iterate over every string in this list of strings and return specific patterns. For example, I need to return all dates, times, and hostnames. The idea is to crate individual lists with so that I can buils a dataframe later. I've already created the RegEx patterns, but I'm having problem with the iteration.

Here is a sample of the list of strings:

```
logs = [
            "Feb 24 2023 20:37:42 somedomain.com Label=Risk_Level cs5=Low cs2Label=Policy act=Deny shost=VD-DONALD dntdom=disney\\\\ ",
            "Feb 24 2023 20:46:10 somedomain.com Label=Risk_Level cs5=High cs2Label=Policy act=Terminate shost=VD-MICKEY dntdom=disney\\\\ ",
            ]
```

Here is the RegEx to capture the date, time, and shost:

```
date = ''.join(re.findall('\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}',logs))
timestamp = ''.join(re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',logs)[0])
target_host = ''.join(re.findall('shost=([^\s]+)',logs))
```

And here are my failed attempts. I keep getting a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. I understand the error, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Attempt 1:

```
date_list = []
for log in logs:
    for date in log:
        date_list.append(date)
print(date_list)
```

Attempt 2:

```
for log in logs:
    for log_item in log:
        if date in log_item:
            print(date)
```

Intended Result:

```
dates_list = ['Feb 24 2023', 'Feb 24 2023']
timestamp_list = ['20:37:42', '20:46:10']
host_list = ['VD-DONALD','VD-MICKEY']
```

Comment: `re.findall` accepts a string not a list as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over each element in the `list` and call `re.search` on each one to extract the matching values from each string.

```py
for log in logs:
    date = re.search(r'\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}',log).group()
    timestamp = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',log).group()
    target_host = re.search(r'shost=([^\s]+)',log).group()
    print(date, timestamp, target_host)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Maybe you find the method split usefull

Ok, so the feature you might be looking for is the method .split() command for python, wich can generate a list from a string, and you can specify the separator (spacebar by default if not specified):

```py
STRING.split("SEPARATOR")
```

So that's what i've done:
(you might have enough with this one)

```py
for log in logs:
     log = log.split()
     monthDate, dayDate, yearDate, timeDate, domain, label, cs5, cs2, act, shost, dntdom = log[0], log[1], log[2], log[3], log[4], log[5], log[6], log[7], log[8], log[9], log[10]
     print("Now you can do whatever: " + dayDate + "-" + monthDate + '-' + yearDate)
```

For my own sake i like to call vars a bit cleaner, also i would like to display Label, cs5,... with just the values instead the keys too.

```py
# so, lets do a function to get rid of the key, just keep the value (position [1])
def displayCleaner(item):
     return item.split('=')[1]
for log in logs:
     log = log.split()
     mDate, dDate, yDate, tDate, domain, label, cs5, cs2, act, shost, dntdom = log[0], log[1], log[2], log[3], log[4], log[5], log[6], log[7], log[8], log[9], log[10]
     label = displayCleaner(label)
     cs5 = displayCleaner(cs5)
     cs2 = displayCleaner(cs2)
     act = displayCleaner(act)
     shost = displayCleaner(shost)
     dntdom = displayCleaner(dntdom)
```

## So, the final code looks like:

```
def displayCleaner(item):
     return item.split('=')[1]

dates_list = []
timestamp_list = []
host_list = []

for log in logs:
     log = log.split()
     mDate, dDate, yDate, tDate, domain, label, cs5, cs2, act, shost, dntdom = log[0], log[1], log[2], log[3], log[4], displayCleaner(log[5]), displayCleaner(log[6]), displayCleaner(log[7]), displayCleaner(log[8]), displayCleaner(log[9]), displayCleaner(log[10])
     myStrDate = str(" ".join([mDate, dDate, yDate]))
     dates_list.append(myStrDate)
     timestamp_list.append(tDate)
     host_list.append(shost)
print(dates_list)
print(timestamp_list)
print(host_list)
```

Comment: That worked well. I voted up the answer but chose the other answer because it's a bit simpler. Thank you for helping!